# How do I add an icon to an app that doesn't have one?

Tags: 11.10

Some apps from the Ubuntu Software Center don't have any icons that Ubuntu Unity desktop even sees, such as ERIC, the Python IDE.  The results are ugly:

[image]

I get this ugly question mark icon, and I can't find any way to configure that icon.   There is no more ability to create a launcher icon on my desktop, or to really control (from the Unity GUI anyways) what icon appears for an app, and if the default ways that Unity finds icons break down, it appears that the results are stuck on "ugly" permanently.

Ubuntu version: 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot)

Update: The answers so far show that something is wrong with my brand new installation, because other people see the icon for eric (eric.png, I guess).  Interestingly, many icons in Ubuntu are SVG, and some are PNG.   I wonder if that's the problem. Still no ability to change or set the icon for any app, either using the GUI, or via VI-and-terminal-and-editing files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon for eric is set in `/usr/share/applications/eric.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eric python IDE
Name[es]=IDE para python Eric
Comment=Full featured Python IDE
Comment[es]=Completo entorno de programaci贸n para Python
Exec=eric
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=eric
Categories=Development;IDE;
StartupNotify=true
```

On disk this appears to be:

```
/usr/share/pixmaps/eric.xpm
```

On my system eric is showing the proper icon in the dash, no idea why yours isn't doing that, but from looking at the default icon you might want to just set another one:

[image]

Comment: Mine also has Icon=eric. Where does the declaration "Icon=eric" resolve to in the file system? /usr/share/icons? There's no path in the entry in eric.desktop, and the /usr/share/icons folder is a root folder containing dozens of subfolders. not exactly clear what's up here.  I tried copying an eric.png to /usr/share/icons/default with NO effect.

Comment: @WarrenP I've updated it to the xpm I found, and asked [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66396/whats-the-absolute-path-of-an-icon-declared-in-a-desktop-file), since I'm not sure.

Comment: The related question asked by Jorge has a very good answer; The theme-related path lookup is so complex that you would need to write a script to determine where the icon really is located.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to edit the corresponding .desktop files in /usr/share/applications. Look for the icons you like in /usr/share/icons.